# Number lookup and sorting in Informix

Tags: sql, vb.net, informix

I have a table in an IBM Informix database wherein there's a column 'level' of data type CHAR(15). If I do a SELECT DISTINCT on that column, the top 5 results are:

- UNKNOWN
- ROOKIE
- LEVEL 1
- LEVEL 2A
- LEVEL 2B

My intention is to write a query that will sort the results in ascending order of the **number** in that column. I have implemented it via VB.NET code, but was wondering if I can do it in the query.

```
' Results is a generic list of a class with properties corresponding to column names
' I am using IDataReader to go through the queried rows and load the data to 'results'
results = results.OrderBy(Of Integer)(Function(p) Utilities.ExtractNumber(p.Level))
```

This is how the ExtractNumber method looks like:

```
Public Shared Function ExtractNumber(ByVal expr As String) As Integer
    Dim number As Integer = 0
    Dim character As Char
    Dim startPos As Integer = -1
    Dim endPos As Integer = -1

    For pos = 0 to expr.Length - 1
        character = expr(pos)

        If Char.IsDigit(character) And startPos = -1 Then
            startPos = pos
        Else If Not Char.IsDigit(character) And startPos > -1 Then
            endPos = pos
            Integer.TryParse(expr.Substring(startPos, endPos - startPos), number)

            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    'Number extends till end of string
    If startPos > -1 And endPos = -1 Then
        Integer.TryParse(expr.Substring(startPos), number)
    EndIf
End Function
```

What my code does is it looks up for the first occurrence of a number in the string for each value in that column. If there are more than one numbers in the string (for example ALPHA 1C 211", it will return 1, which is the first number. If there are no numbers present, like in "unknown", it will just return 0.

What I did above could be easily done using, say, Regex.Split but I didn't use that as it was returning a string array with empty elements preceding the number.

Is there a way I can do this number extraction in an SQL query? Maybe use some kind of string manipulation to get rid of everything but the first number? I'm not allowed to write a function though, so I have to do all this in one query, if at all possible. Any pointers?

Comment: i was going to recommend an sp until i read your last line. Unfortunately Informix has fair poor inbuilt string handling capabilities and most anything above a simple replace/match will require a stored procedure... Now, even if you do manage to knock this up in a query, you'll probably find the expense of informix creating a temp table to order the rows will be more than letting VB manipulate the results.

Comment: If you're not allowed to write a function, don't bother with attempting that in an SQL expression — unless you can write a loop-less VB expression that does the job.  Regardless of the strengths of Informix's string handling functions (which are basic), if you can't do it without a loop in VB, you're unlikely to be able to do it in SQL without a function.

Comment: Given that there is no digit in ROOKIE or UNKNOWN, what number do they have (0)? Given LEVEL 2A and LEVEL 2B, are both assigned the same number 2? One of the better ways to deal with this would be to modify the table defining these possible values to include a 'sort order' column, specifying how you want the results presented. You can allocate 0 to UNKNOWN, 10 to ROOKIE, 20 to LEVEL 1, 30 to LEVEL 2A and 40 to LEVEL 2B, etc. Leaving gaps means you can add data without having to renumber, a basic trick (or even BASIC trick). The sort number only appears in the table where the codes are defined.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The table has about 2.2 million rows.

Comment: So you don't have a lookup table that defines the valid codes?  Hmm; well, the design of the table is less than stellar, but that's not at all unusual, sadly.  I assume that lookup codes like that have a table that defines the valid values — and other attributes of the values, such as sort order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I noted originally, while you can't use a user-defined function, you can't solve this problem.  It is quite simply not doable.

If you can use a function, then try this for size:

```
CREATE FUNCTION find_first_number(str VARCHAR(32), def INTEGER DEFAULT 0)
    RETURNING INTEGER AS number
    WITH(NOT VARIANT);

    DEFINE i    INTEGER;
    DEFINE j    INTEGER;
    DEFINE l    INTEGER;
    DEFINE c    CHAR(1);
    DEFINE nstr VARCHAR(32);

    IF str IS NULL THEN
        RETURN def;
    END IF;
    LET l = LENGTH(str);
    FOR i = 0 TO l
        LET c = SUBSTR(str, i, 1);
        IF c >= "0" AND c <= "9" THEN
            LET nstr = c;
            FOR j = i + 1 TO l
                LET c = SUBSTR(str, j, 1);
                IF c >= "0" AND c <= "9" THEN
                    LET nstr = nstr || c;
                ELSE
                    RETURN nstr;    -- String of digits in middle of string
                END IF;
            END FOR;
            RETURN nstr;    -- String of digits at end of string
        END IF;
    END FOR;

    RETURN def;

END FUNCTION;
```

The `WITH(NOT VARIANT)` clause tells the optimizer that for the same input, the function always produces the same output (so the output is invariant for a given input).

Test code:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE ffn_test
(
    str     VARCHAR(32),
    def     INTEGER,
    num     INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO ffn_test VALUES("UNKNOWN", 0, 0);
INSERT INTO ffn_test VALUES("ROOKIE", -1, -1);
INSERT INTO ffn_test VALUES("LEVEL 1", 0, 1);
INSERT INTO ffn_test VALUES("LEVEL 2A", 0, 2);
INSERT INTO ffn_test VALUES("LEVEL 2B", 0, 2);
INSERT INTO ffn_test VALUES("LEVEL 20", 0, 20);
INSERT INTO ffn_test VALUES("LEVEL 999", 0, 999);
INSERT INTO ffn_test VALUES("LEVEL 3.0", 0, 3);
INSERT INTO ffn_test VALUES(NULL, 0, 0);

SELECT str, def, num,
       find_first_number(str, def) AS result,
       CASE WHEN num = find_first_number(str, def) THEN "PASS" ELSE "FAIL" END pass_fail
  FROM ffn_test;
```

Test output:

```
UNKNOWN     0           0           0           PASS
ROOKIE      -1          -1          -1          PASS
LEVEL 1     0           1           1           PASS
LEVEL 2A    0           2           2           PASS
LEVEL 2B    0           2           2           PASS
LEVEL 20    0           20          20          PASS
LEVEL 999   0           999         999         PASS
LEVEL 3.0   0           3           3           PASS
            0           0           0           PASS
```

Answer (score 1):

Are your levels limited to a single digit or at least a known set?  If yes, a case statement might work.  You would have to play with the match pattern to get the right result for "ALPHA 2C 211" based on your knowledge of what valid values are.  This was reasonably fast on a varchar(256) field in a table with about 89K rows.  Not sure about 2.2 mil.:

```
SELECT
   CASE
   WHEN pr_last_name matches("*1*")
      THEN 1
   WHEN pr_last_name matches("*2*")
      THEN 2
   WHEN pr_last_name matches("*3*")
      THEN 3
   WHEN pr_last_name matches("*4*")
      THEN 3
   WHEN pr_last_name matches("*5*")
      THEN 4
   WHEN pr_last_name matches("*5*")
      THEN 5
   WHEN pr_last_name matches("*6*")
      THEN 6
   ELSE
      0
   END,
count(*)
FROM person
group by 1
order by 1
```

Sample output:

```
0   88255
1   469
2   231
3   193
4   53
6   37
```

Comment: No multiple matches as the case statement will exit with the first match.  "1" in this case.  If there were 16 valid values, just do the double digit checks first.  This is not ideal, but @Sayak requested a single SQL with no SPL.

Comment: It doesn't bear thinking about if you have to extend it to handle 999!  But yes, it does meet his crtierion.